# two response Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am sending via ajax and I am receiving 2 responses.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo $this->html->url(array('controller'=>'whatsapps','action'=>'wbulk')) ?>",
    data: {
        contact: res.telefonos[i],
        idwhats: idwhat,
        mensaje: res.mensaje,
        foto: res.image
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response, status) {
        console.log(response);
        var res2 = response;
        if (res2.success) {

            enviados++;

            res2['campana'] = idcamp;
            res2['idwhats'] = idwhat;
            //console.log(res);

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "<?php echo $this->html->url(array('controller'=>'whatsapps','action'=>'GuardarEnvio')) ?>",
                data: res2,
                dataType: "html"
            })
        } else {
            errores++;
        }

    }
})
```

Response:

```
{"success":false,"motivo":"not-authorized"}{
"name": "",
"message": "",
"url": "\/cakephp\/gvl\/whatsapps\/wbulk"}
```

I need to split this up. I only need the success array.

---

**UPDATE**

I just send one request but when the api im using shows error it reponse me with two arrays but i just expect this:

> {"success":false,"motivo":"not-authorized"}

The second ajax should work if the success is true

Comment: You're sending two AJAX requests.

Comment: Could you please try to describe your problem, what you tried, what you expected and what it produces. Please read up on 'how to ask questions'. Thank you.

Comment: you are using cakephp. what is your error

Comment: this sends me the appi: **{"success":false,"motivo":"not-authorized"}**, this sends cakephp: **{"name": "","message": "","url":"\/cakephp\/gvl\/whatsapps\/wbulk"}